# Android: Individually update image in gallery

Tags: android, image, gallery, adapter

I am following the [gallery tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gallery.html) and I am trying to figure out how to change individual images in the gallery without recreating the gallery object.  I dont want to recreate the gallery object because the images will be updated every few seconds, and when you start scrolling the gallery, then you create a new gallery object, the gallery position will return to the beginning, which is not what I want.

Does anyone know of a way to access each image in the gallery individually so I can update it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [getChildAt](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#getChildAt%28int%29) api call and get the view of a particular position. Then you can change the data of the view the way you like it...if you require further information on the data that your view holds make sure that you tag the the required data to the view in bindView/getView call of the adapter associated with the gallery widget

Comment: My ImageAdapter is basically the same as in the tutorial, except I have another method to update the image.  How can I pass a ViewGroup to my new method when calling it?